# Увеличить высоту дива по его содержимому с переносами текста и заданным max-height

Tags: javascript, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`<div id="mta">` имеет наименьшую высоту (под одну строку).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`<div id="mta">` - 'открыт'.

Как сделать, чтобы при 'открытом' `<div id="mta">`, - его содержимое выводилось полностью.
Сейчас длинные слова, например, `X01234567890_01234567890_01234567890` обрезаны.
В идеале, сделать, чтобы и заполнение было плотнее, т.е. использовать свободное место такое как после `abc def`, а длинным словам делать разрыв (перенос), и совместимость в браузерах.

Можно для него убрать `display: table;` это не критично - моя попытка выводить всё содержимое при 'открытии' дива. Пробовал с этим: `word-wrap: break-word;` - не получилось ...
В добавок нужно ограничить высоту этого открываемого дива, чтобы длинный текст не создавал его слишком большим, например, высотой `max-height: 80px;` С этим тоже у меня косяк, помогите плиз.

```js
function openclose() {
  let d = document.getElementById('mtc');
  if (d.children[1].style.display === 'none') {
    d.children[1].style.display = 'block';
    d.children[2].style.display = 'block';
    d.children[3].style.display = 'table';
    d.children[3].style.width = 100 + '%';
  } else {
    d.children[1].style.display = 'none';
    d.children[2].style.display = 'none';
    d.children[3].style.display = 'block';
    d.children[3].style.width = 82 + '%';
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f3e7d8;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#msa,
#mta {
  float: left;
  height: 18px;
  background: #953b39;
  color: #3e1a01;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 160px; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="mtc" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 18px; background: #49afcd;">
    <div id="msa" style="width:18%;" onclick="openclose();">&nbsp;...</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 82%; height: 86px; display: none; background: lightcoral;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 18px; width: 18%; height: 68px; display: none; background: yellow;"></div>
    <div id="mta" style="width:82%; overflow: hidden;" onclick="">X01234567890_01234567890_01234567890 abc def 01234567890_01234567890_01234567890 Y01234567890_01234567890_01234567890 abc def 01234567890_01234567890_01234567890 Z01234567890_01234567890_01234567890 abc def 01234567890_01234567890_01234567890.</div>
    <span
      style="display:none;">0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div id="mta">` не имеет минимальную высоту, у него фиксированная высота, `height` это фиксированная высота, `min-height` это минимальная высота

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, да, неудачно выразился при описании того, что из двух картинок на первой, - *наименьшая высота* данного дива ... я пробовал min-height | max-height , thanks

Comment: для #msa,#mta{ word-break: break-all;} но код реально ужасен

Comment: @Armen, да `word-break: break-all;` действительно *уплотняет* так, как я хотел, спасибо.

Comment: @Alex не за что рад помочь